# Express Route foreach and if/else statment give me both if and else response

Tags: javascript, express

```js
//Modules
const express = require('express'); 

//Initializing
let router = express.Router()

//Midlewares
router.use(express.json())

//My Vacumms
let acs = [
  {
    id:1,
    name:"acs1",
    actionType:{
      state:false,
      temperature:1
    }
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name:"acs2",
    actionType:{
      state:false,
      temperature:1
    }
  },
  {
    id:3,
    name:"acs3",
    actionType:{
      state:false,
      temperature:1
    }
  }
]

//Main Page /Vacuums
router.get('/:id/:actionType/:OfOn', (req, res)=>{
  let Adress = req.params
  new Promise
  acs.forEach(Vacu =>{
    if(Adress.id == parseInt(Vacu.id)){
      for(type in Vacu.actionType){
          if(Vacu.actionType[type] == Vacu.actionType[Adress.actionType]){
            Vacu.actionType[type] = Adress.OfOn
            res.json(acs)
          }else if(Vacu.actionType[Adress.actionType] == undefined){
            res.json("Action type not found")
          }
      }
    }else{
      console.log("Wtf is going on!!! D:D::DD::D:D");
    }
  })
  
})

module.exports = router
```

> ERROR: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they
>   are sent to the client
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
>       at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Desktop\NodeTutorial\HomeWork2\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
>       at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Desktop\NodeTutorial\HomeWork2\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
>       at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\Desktop\NodeTutorial\HomeWork2\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
>       at C:\Users\Desktop\NodeTutorial\HomeWork2\Routers\acs.js:49:17
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at C:\Users\Desktop\NodeTutorial\HomeWork2\Routers\acs.js:42:7
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Brian\Desktop\NodeTutorial\HomeWork2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\Users\Desktop\NodeTutorial\HomeWork2\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Desktop\NodeTutorial\HomeWork2\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>   Wtf is going on!!! D:D::DD::D:D Wtf is going on!!! D:D::DD::D:D

When i test with Postman everything works fine, but i still get those errors... 
i dont know what im going wrong!

//i want to manipulate my acs Array through the adress bar with request.params!

Answer (score 0):

Usually it happens when you trying to response twice. I think, that problem in this loop. Try to break the loop after u send the response

```
  if(Adress.id == parseInt(Vacu.id)){
  for(type in Vacu.actionType){
      if(Vacu.actionType[type] == Vacu.actionType[Adress.actionType]){
        Vacu.actionType[type] = Adress.OfOn
        res.json(acs)
        break
      }else if(Vacu.actionType[Adress.actionType] == undefined){
        res.json("Action type not found")
        break
      }
  }
```